# R: Split A parent Vector to Some Overlapping Subvectors with Some Rebounding Subvectors Element

Tags: r, vector

I want to split a parent vector called `ts` into some subvectors with the following conditions:

1. Each sub-vector has an equal and constant length `l`.
2. The sub-vectors overlap one another with a `constant` number of element
3. Number of sub-vector is more than `length(ts)`
4. Some block elements can be rebounding, in such a way that the start-to-end elements of the parent vector make a subvector.
5. Each subvector is unique in its element's composition.

For illustration, consider a parent vector of `1 to 10` with a subvector size of 3 consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5
4, 5, 6
5, 6, 7
6, 7, 8
7, 8, 9
8, 9, 10
9, 10, 1
10, 1, 2
```

Can I have more subvectors than the 10 listed above?

Comment: Well, depends if you allow unsorted vectors, you could have `2, 1, 3`?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do the 10 elements you list? otherwise, this might be more of a Cross-Validated question

Comment: I need the subvectors each to contain consecutive elements of the parent Victor.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to do actually implement it, but you essentially end up doing modular arithmetic

```
myVec <- 1:10
subLen <- 3

purrr::map(
  myVec, 
 seq, length.out = subLen
) |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) ifelse(x > max(myVec), x - max(myVec), x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `embed`

```
n <- 15
v <- 1:n
l <- 3
embed(c(v, head(v, l - 1)), l)[, l:1]
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    2    3    4
 [3,]    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    5    6
 [5,]    5    6    7
 [6,]    6    7    8
 [7,]    7    8    9
 [8,]    8    9   10
 [9,]    9   10   11
[10,]   10   11   12
[11,]   11   12   13
[12,]   12   13   14
[13,]   13   14   15
[14,]   14   15    1
[15,]   15    1    2
```