# R: Split A Vector Into Subvectors with Overlaps and Rebounding

Tags: r, vector, split

I want to split a parent vector called `v` into some subvectors with the following conditions:

**Edited for clarity**

1. Each sub-vector has an equal length `l` which is less than the number
   of the parent vector `v`.
2. Each sub-vector is unique in its elements' composition and contains
   consecutive elements.
3. Elements of a particular sub-vector overlap with elements of
   previous and subsequent sub-vector.
4. The same Element must not overlap more than `l - 1` times in consecutive sub-vectors as starting element of every sub-vector is arranged in ascending order.
5. Some block elements can be rebounding, in such a way that the
   start-to-end elements of the parent vector make a sub-vector.
6. The input should be a vector for the parent vector `v`, and an
   integer for the block length `l`. While the output should be a list
   of vectors (not a matrix) such that each sub-vector is output as a
   vector and the list of all sub-vectors is a list.

For illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 3` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3
    x2, x3, x4
            x4, x5, x6
                x5, x6, x7
                        x7, x8, x9
                            x8, x9, x10
                                    x10, x1, x2
```

What I do is form a series of subvectors each with length `l =3` with starting elements being progressive in nature (`x1, x2 x4, x5, x7, x8, x10`) and not recursive. The third sub-vector starts from `x4` and not `x3` because starting it from `x3` will make `x3` overlap `l` times and not  `l - 1` times at that stage. The same consideration is applied to the 5th and the 7th sub-vector.

For another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 4` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4
    x2, x3, x4, x5
        x3, x4, x5, x6
                x5, x6, x7, x8
                    x6, x7, x8, x9
                        x7, x8, x9, x10
                                x9, x10, x1, x2
                                    x10, x1, x2, x3
```

What I do is form a series of subvectors each with length `l =3` with starting elements being progressive in nature (`x1, x2, x3, x5, x6, x7, x9, x10`) and not recursive. The third sub-vector starts from `x5` and not `x4` because starting it from `x4` will make `x4` overlap `l` times and not  `l - 1` times at that stage. The same consideration is applied to the 8th and the 7th sub-vector.

Yet another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 5` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
    x2, x3, x4, x5, x6
        x3, x4, x5, x6, x7
            x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
                    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10
                        x7, x8, x9, x10, x1
                            x8, x9, x10, x1, x2
                                x9, x10, x1, x2, x3
```

Yet another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 6` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6
    x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7
        x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
            x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9
                x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10
                        x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2
                            x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3
                                x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4
                                    x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
```

Yet another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 7` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7
    x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
        x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9
            x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10
                x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1
                    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2
                            x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4
                                x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
                                    x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6
```

Yet another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 8` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
    x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9
        x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10
            x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1
                x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2
                    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3
                        x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4
                                x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6
                                    x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7
```

Yet another illustration, consider a parent vector of `x1` to `x10` with a subvector size of `l = 9` consecutive elements of its parent vector as follows:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9
    x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10
        x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1
            x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2
                x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3
                    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4
                        x7, x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
                            x8, x9, x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6
                                    x10, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
```

**What I Need**

I need an `R` code that gives me the output I want according to the conditions above. You can use `v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` for parent vector input with your choice of `1 < l < length(v)` in your `R code` test.

Comment: I am here to explain ambiguity or correct contradictions.

Comment: The last row of the answer should be omitted since it introduces a third 2.

Comment: Also it is not consecutive.  11 comes after 10, not 1.

Comment: In your last comment, `rebounding` allows a subvector to continue from the beginning of the parent vector, presented in `condition 4`.

Comment: I am looking into this `ts <- 10; m <- 1:ts`; `l <- 3`; `embed(c(m, head(m, l - 1)), l)[, l:1]` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128743/r-split-a-parent-vector-to-some-overlapping-subvectors-with-some-rebounding-sub

Comment: your last row breaks the rule 3, isn't it?

Comment: I have adjusted my output expectation @ThomasIsCoding, please check it out.

Comment: What about `10` and `1`? Shouldn't they appear twice like any other element?

Comment: now your condition 4 doesn't hold since you have the third 2.

Comment: By rule 4, `(l-1) * length(v)` must be a multiple of `l`, which means that `length(v)` must be a multiple of `l`. So this is not solvable for the case you mention, where `length(v)` is 10 and `l` is 3.

Comment: I have reconsidered my conditions especially the 4th, and I have come up with solvable conditions, @AndrewGustar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `zoo::rollapply()`.

```r
library(zoo)

fun <- \(v, l) c(v, v[1:(l-1)]) |> # append vector beginning to also get combinations of first and last elements
  rollapply(l, \(x) x) |> # apply window
  split(seq_along(v)) |> # from matrix to list
  (`[`)(seq_along(v) %% l != 0) # remove unwanted subvectors


fun(1:10, 3)
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 3 4
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] 5 6 7
#> 
#> $`7`
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1]  8  9 10
#> 
#> $`10`
#> [1] 10  1  2
```

```r
fun(1:10, 4)
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 3 4 5 6
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] 5 6 7 8
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> $`7`
#> [1]  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $`9`
#> [1]  9 10  1  2
#> 
#> $`10`
#> [1] 10  1  2  3
```

Comment: The list names are introduced by the use of `split()`. If you don't want them, use `unname()`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work on all given examples, since they seem redundant let me demonstrate on a couple of them :

```r
fun <- function(v, l) {
  lapply(seq_along(v), function(i) {
    c(v, v)[seq(i, i + l - 1)]
  })[-seq(l, length(v), by = l)]
}

fun(1:10, 3)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 5 6 7
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1]  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 10  1  2

fun(1:10, 7)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1]  6  7  8  9 10  1  2
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1]  8  9 10  1  2  3  4
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1]  9 10  1  2  3  4  5
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 10  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Maybe using `seq_along(v)[-seq(l, length(v), l)]` instead of `seq_along(v)` and skipping it at the end would be an alternative? Or storing some results to be used again: `i <- seq_along(v)` `j <- seq(l) - 1` `v <- c(v, v)` `lapply(i[i %% l != 0], \(i) v[i + j])`.

Answer (score 1):

I gather you have removed the consecutive condition which was never explained but I assumed meant that each element must be 1 greater than the prior element in each subvector except for recycling.

In that case it is even simpler since we no longer have to check the consecutive condition.  Based on the example there are no zeros in `myVec` so we will use zero to signify rows that were eliminated -- we could use NA but it would involve slightly longer code but that seems unnecessary so we stick to the shorter code.

Now, for each row `i` of `tab` we run `table` on all elements of rows up to and including the current row zeroing out rows that were already eliminated in prior iterations.  Then take the counts corresponding to the current row's elements and if all of those counts are less than `subLen` set ok[i] to TRUE and otherwise FALSE.  Then at the end we subset `tab` to the TRUE elements in `ok`.

```
myVec <- 1:10
subLen <- 3

Embed <- function(vec, n) embed(vec, n)[, n:1]

tab <- head(Embed(c(myVec, myVec), subLen), length(myVec))

ok <- rep(TRUE, length(myVec))
for(i in 1:nrow(tab)) {
  ok[i] <- max(table(tab[1:i, ] * ok[1:i])[as.character(tab[i, ])]) < subLen
}
tab[ok, ]
```

### Old

We assume that rebounding means that `min(myVec)` can immediately follow `max(myVec)` and it will still be regarded as "consecutive".  We assume that consecutive means that the values increase by adding 1 except for rebounding.

Use `embed` to create the `tab` matrix with the subvectors as rows and also create a `consec` matrix whose columns are the valid possible "consecutive" sub-vectors of length `subLen` taking into account rebounding.

Then iterate through the rows of `tab` setting ok to FALSE if that row is not a column in `consec` or any element of it would result in more than `subLen` occurrences. Finally subset `tab` by it.

In the question 0 is not an element of `myVec` and we assume that that is true in general so that we can zero out rows that do not satisfy the condition.  If that were not true, in general, we could NA out those rows instead but using 0 leads to shorter code.

```
myVec <- 1:10
subLen <- 3

Embed <- function(vec, n) embed(vec, n)[, n:1]

tab <- head(Embed(c(myVec, myVec), subLen), length(myVec))
consec <- t(Embed(rep(seq(min(myVec), max(myVec)), 2), subLen))

ok <- rep(TRUE, length(myVec))
for(i in 1:nrow(tab)) {
  ok[i] <- any(colSums(consec != tab[i, ]) == 0) &&
    max(table(tab[1:i, ] * ok[1:i])[as.character(tab[i, ])]) < subLen
}
tab[ok, ]
```

giving

```
tab[ok, ]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    3
## [2,]    2    3    4
## [3,]    4    5    6
## [4,]    5    6    7
## [5,]    7    8    9
## [6,]    8    9   10
```

Comment: This is a case where the subvectors are not allowed to rebound. Try it for `subLen <- 7` to confirm my claim.

Comment: Yes, this your code works for `subLen <- 3` because rebounding does not come to play here but in the case of `subLen <- 4`, `subLen <- 5`, `subLen <- 6`, `subLen <- 7`, `subLen <- 8` and `subLen <- 9`.

Comment: I have a challenge of input such that if I put vector or time series, it does not take for instance, `set.seed(289805)`;
`myVec <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)` or `myVec <- c(1, 7, 3, 8, 2, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1)` instead of the sequence `myVec <- 1:10` you originally used in your code. The time series object is what I want to use it for.

Comment: It works correctly according to the definitions at the beginning of the answer.  There are no rows output which is correct since there are no rows which are consecutive rows according to the definition of consecutive in the answer.

Comment: Oh no! Thanks for your trial, your definition is not in line with my desired concept. I look forward to a better answer.

Comment: The question did not define the rules precisely so I  stated the assumptions used to avoid ambiguity.  If you want something different it is up to you to provide precise definitions.

Comment: I have input as a `vector` in the question now, I make use of the `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` as my input to be able to track the position and frequency of every element in the series.

Comment: Your answer could have been the best if it had accepted a `vector` instead of a `sequence` as intake

Comment: The answer uses the example you provided. If the example is no good then you will needs to fix the question.

Comment: I have reconsidered my conditions especially the 4th, and I have come up with solvable conditions.

Comment: My understanding is that you have removed the consecutive condition where each element of a subvector must be one greater than the prior element except for recycling.  Have removed that condition from the code but it is otherwise unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try the code below

```
# split vector into subvectors following all rules
f <- function(ts, l) {
    m <- seq_along(ts)
    asplit(embed(c(ts, head(ts, l - 1)), l)[m %% l > 0 & m %% l, l:1], 1)
}
```

and we can run a couple of tests for example

```
set.seed(0)
v <- runif(10)
l <- 3:(length(v) - 1)
lapply(l, \(k) f(v, k))
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978

[[1]][[6]]
[1] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[1]][[7]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753

[[2]][[5]]
[1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978

[[2]][[6]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[2]][[7]]
[1] 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087

[[2]][[8]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897

[[3]][[4]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753

[[3]][[5]]
[1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[3]][[6]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972

[[3]][[7]]
[1] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087

[[3]][[8]]
[1] 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897

[[4]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753

[[4]][[4]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978

[[4]][[5]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[4]][[6]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087

[[4]][[7]]
[1] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239

[[4]][[8]]
[1] 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534

[[4]][[9]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897

[[5]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753

[[5]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978

[[5]][[4]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[5]][[5]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972

[[5]][[6]]
[1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087

[[5]][[7]]
[1] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534

[[5]][[8]]
[1] 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078

[[5]][[9]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
[8] 0.9446753

[[6]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753
[8] 0.6607978

[[6]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
[8] 0.6291140

[[6]][[4]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
[8] 0.8966972

[[6]][[5]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972
[8] 0.2655087

[[6]][[6]]
[1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087
[8] 0.3721239

[[6]][[7]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239
[8] 0.5728534

[[6]][[8]]
[1] 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078
[8] 0.2016819

[[6]][[9]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
[8] 0.8983897


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
[8] 0.9446753 0.6607978

[[7]][[2]]
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753
[8] 0.6607978 0.6291140

[[7]][[3]]
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
[8] 0.6291140 0.8966972

[[7]][[4]]
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
[8] 0.8966972 0.2655087

[[7]][[5]]
[1] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972
[8] 0.2655087 0.3721239

[[7]][[6]]
[1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087
[8] 0.3721239 0.5728534

[[7]][[7]]
[1] 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239
[8] 0.5728534 0.9082078

[[7]][[8]]
[1] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
[8] 0.9082078 0.2016819

[[7]][[9]]
[1] 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
[8] 0.8983897 0.9446753
```

Comment: `Fourth condition of the question` is not met also the output condition on the 6th item is not met.

Comment: @DanielJames Why is the 4th condition not met? I used the function `isvalid` to check if any number appears less than `l` times.

Comment: @DanielJames Also, for your 6th condition, you can use `asplit(x,1)` to split the matrix `x` by rows into list of vectors, which is just one more step than the current solution.

Comment: I have reconsidered my conditions especially the 4th, and I have come up with solvable conditions

Comment: @DanielJames Thanks for providing more info! Plz see my update.